# Выпадающий список в выпадающем списке HTML

Tags: html, select

Подскажите пожалуйста такую вещь. Как сделать `select` в `select`-те. Это не аккордион. а именно список в списке. Для примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это штука есть в `Приват24` - украинский банк.

как такое сделать?

Comment: ужасный UI не делайте так

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich ну а как моно сделать подобно? пример.

Comment: Что вы вообще хотите сделать для пользователя?

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich сортировку. юзер выбирает год и нажимает на до которого месяца показывать.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сделать это с помощью вложенных список (ol, ul). Делать это с помощью select-ов действительно плохо. Но даже если вы и сделаете с помощью select-а, то потом задать свои стили будет очень проблематично. Проще работать со вложенными (или многоуровневыми списками), а в форме создать hidden поле, куда записывать данные с выбором этого поля. Основы можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.sitehere.ru/urok-3-spiski#vlozhspisok).
А вот дальше необходимо будет самостоятельно с помощью JS написать функционал, в зависимости от того, нужно ли динамически добавлять элементы при нажатии и т.д. Но работать проще в дальнейшем именно с обычными списками.